# Каким образом можно обучить ИИ распознавать лицо?

Tags: python, искусственный-интеллект

Дело в том, что мне нужен вариант без готовых библиотек по типу TensorFlow, Keras  и подобные, только вспомогательные по типу numpy, pandas. Я ищу много информации по поводу обучения ИИ, но практически в каждом вариант есть уже готовая модель.
Я не прошу вас написать мне код, я прошу, чтобы вы подсказали мне методы или алгоритмы по каким я бы смог обучить ИИ этому, и по возможности статьи для этого.
Благодарю.

UPD:Кратко о моем проекте - мне нужен этот ИИ для проекта о распозновании эмоции на лице человека. По этому мне сначало нужен ИИ для распознавания лица, чтобы второй ИИ распознавания эмоций работал только с фотографией лица

Comment: Вам нужно по "частям" добираться к вашей реализации, без использования готовых вариантов.
По сути вначале нужно понять как на кадре или фото, найти лицо. Фото состоит из пикселей, и алгоритмы поиска на пикселях "образа" человека или стазу лица.
Но ваш алгоритм, будет медленным и объемным :) Я писал нейронку, классифицирующую слова на русском. Это проще, но там я научился и придумал кучу своих фишек, прокачав свои знания =)
Но я бы на вашем месте вначале понял как делают другие и если не устраивает менял на своё. Но мало где толково описывают методики. Куча воды а сути нет.

Comment: И к примеру Пайтон использует вычислительные мощности видеокарты, а вы только процессора, что замедляет в разы процесс. Так что осознайте кучу стадий и технологий, которые в этом участвуют ;) Но я вас не отговариваю, самому познать "суть" это хорошо ;)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIiQeWJgjLw Можен это поможет? Смотрел сегодня, вспомнил про вас :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя написать систему распознавания лица "без готовых библиотек" не разобравшись предварительно

- как вообще обучаются нейросети и более глубоко - а как работают методы машинного обучения. Ну, на пару семестров тут хвати чего изучать. Впрочем, можно взять любую книгу по машинному обучению -  и подробно штудировать.
- как на изображении выделяется некий объект (не лицо, а именно объект). А для этого освоить кучу специальных методов обработки изображений, их особенности, сильные и слабые стороны. Еще как минимум семестр.
- как написать те процедуры, которые находятся "под капотом" у TF и реализовать их самостоятельно, причем так, чтобы они не падали при первой же ошибки. Ну,зная какой коллектив работал над TF и даже поделив это число на 10 (поскольку будете реализовывать только часть этого пакета) все равно энтузиазма должно существенно поубавиться, ибо эта задача на пару лет. Сомнительный "пэт-проект", если честно.
- Но допустим, вы все это осилите. А теперь внимание вопрос. Чтобы обучить нейросеть распознаванию лиц надо ей скормить пару десятков тысяч (!) изображений, причем размеченных заранее. Вы уже решили, где вы этот датасет возьмете? И как будете тестировать свои результаты?

Я это к чему виду. Надеяться самостоятельно реализовать распознавание лиц, но без вспомогательных средств - причем неважно, будет это TF, OpenCV,PyTorch etc. - можно только, если абсолютно ничего не понимаешь ни в распознавании, ни в нейросетях, ни в программировании. Подсказки тут не помогут -  только последовательное и серьезное изучение темы. Увы.
Стоит-ли тратить свой самый главный ресурс -  время на заведомо нереализуемую задачу? Решение принимайте сами.